# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un "option" de un "select"?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, codeigniter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un select, el cual se llena al traer los datos desde una base de datos. Lo que intento hacer es que al seleccionar una opción del select, se deshabilite para que el usuario no pueda acceder de nuevo a esa opción, a menos que cambie la option y se vuelva a activar. ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano?
Cabe mencionar que me encuentro trabajando sobre CodeIgniter.

Agradezco su atención a la comunidad.

Dejo una captura de lo que intento hacer.

Comment: Agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: No creo que puedas hacer lo que quieres, ya que al "**desabilitar**" un "**option**", su valor no puede ser utilizado en el **select** y por tanto no sera enviado en el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta pero si lo que quieres es que el usuario luego de seleccionar una opcion del select, no pueda cambiar esta, se me ha ocurrido la solucion con CSS asi:

El HTML:

```
<select class="opciones" id="opciones" readonly >
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

El CSS:

```
.deshabilita{
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

El JS:

```
let opciones = document.getElementById("opciones");
opciones.onchange=changeEventHandler;

function changeEventHandler(event) {
    opciones.classList.add("deshabilita");

}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando aqui:
https://codepen.io/coderalexis/pen/QoLpMe